# React Hook Form: when I render a TextField (materialUI) and provide the Field: {onChange} it says onChange undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm literally following their documentation and also tried the code from an article on github. I have the most recent version installed. Still not working. So frustateeeeeed.

```js
 const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm()
```

This is the component I return:

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   <Controller
     name="lastName"
     control={control}
     defaultValue=""
     render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
       <TextField
         label="Last Name"
         variant="filled"
         value={field.value}
         onChange={field.onChange}
         error={!!fieldState.error}
         helperText={fieldState.error ? fieldState.error.message : null}
       />
     )}
     rules={{ required: 'Last name required' }}

   <Button type="submit" disabled={!stripe} buttonText="Pay"></Button>
 </form>
```

It simply keeps giving the error that field.value, field.onchange, fieldState.error are undefined. I tried destructuring too. Doesn't work either.

Comment: The problem might be related to somewhere else. Could you share your working repo?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-worker-mdqx3

I recommend passing the `ref` as well.

Comment: After 1 day of spending time, I finally got fixed by your code. Kindly copy paste my code to your editor for clear understanding..

Comment: <Controller 
       control={control}    name={ name }  label={ label }
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState }) =>   (
                  <TextField     fullWidth   
                  required={ required } {...field} inputRef={ref} error={isError} ></TextField>
        )}
        >
      </Controller>

Comment: <FormInput  required name="firstName" type="text" label="First name" {...(register('firstName'))} inputRef={register}/>
                                                                                                                                        <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" {...(register('lastName'))} inputRef={register} />